# LINQ - How to get recipes with all ingredients match

Tags: linq, recipe

I'm having trouble finding recipes that contain all of selected ingredients.

Models:

Recipe

```
public int Id { get; set; }
[StringLength(64)]
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
[StringLength(256)]
public string CoverURL { get; set; }
public int PreparationTime { get; set; }
public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
public RecipeCategory Category { get; set; }
public List<RecipeImage> Images { get; set; }
public List<RecipeIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
public List<RecipeSpice> Spices { get; set; }
```

Ingredient

```
public int Id { get; set; }
[StringLength(64)]
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<RecipeIngredient> Recipes { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
```

RecipeIngredient

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public double Quantity { get; set; }
public  Unit Unit { get; set; }
public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
```

And I tried

```
List<Ingredient> selectedIngredients = new List<Ingredient>();
selectedIngredients = _vm.Ingredients.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();

List<Recipe> recipes = new List<Recipe>();
recipes = _vm.Recipes.Where(x => selectedIngredients.Contains(x.Ingredients));
```

But it return a error:

> cannot convert from
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RecipeApp.Model.RecipeIngredient>' to
> 'RecipeApp.Model.Ingredient'

I know it's a problem becouse "selectedIngredients" is a List of Ingredients, and a "x.Ingredients" is a list of RecipeIngredients. But I can't do it properly.

I did it, but maybe someone will do it better?

```
        List<Recipe> recipes = new List<Recipe>();
        List<Ingredient> selectedIngredients = new List<Ingredient>();
        
        selectedIngredients = _vm.Ingredients.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
        var recipeIngredients = _vm.Recipes.Select(r => r.Ingredients).ToList();
        
        foreach(var ingredientsList in recipeIngredients)
        {
            var recipe = ingredientsList.Select(x => x.Recipe)
                                        .Where(u => ingredientsList
                                            .Select(l => l.Ingredient.Id)
                                            .Intersect(selectedIngredients
                                                .Select(l2 => l2.Id))
                                            .Contains(u.Id))
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

            if (recipe != null)
                recipes.Add(recipe);
```

Comment: You can't use `Contains` to see if a `List` is in another `List`, regardless of the type mismatch. Also, aren't you testing backwards? Also there is no point in e.g. assigning a new `List` to `recipes` and immediately discarding it by re-assigning something to `recipes`. That just creates wasted garbage.

Comment: `var recipes = _vm.Recipes.Where(r => selectedIngredients.All(si => r.Ingredients.Select(ri => ri.Ingredient).Contains(si)).ToList();`. It would probably be better if `Recipe.Ingredients` was named `Recipe.RecipeIngredients` to reflect the contained type.

Comment: @NetMage Thank you for help but, your code have a little bug. For example if Recipe1 have 3 ingredients (A, B, C) and Recipe2 have 2 ingredients (A, B), then if I selected only ingredients A and B then code return me Recipe1 and Recipe2. In this example code should return only Recipe2. 
But if I selected all of ingredients (A, B, C) then your code return only Recipe1.

Comment: That means the test is backwards: `var recipes = _vm.Recipes.Where(r => r.Ingredients.Select(ri => ri.Ingredient).All(si => selectedIngredients.Contains(si)).ToList();`